# Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set

Tags: java, macos, maven

1) Downloaded maven.
2) tar xzvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
3) I tried to install maven 3.3.9 on my Mac and when I check the "mvn --version" it says

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match

4) My bash_profile looks like
`export M2_HOME=/Users/vijay/Documents/Softwares/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4096m"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home`

Can anyone suggest to resolve it and get the maven installed corectly on my Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set environment variables like :

export M2_HOME=/Users/vijay/Documents/Softwares/apache-maven-3.3.9

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx4096m

export PATH=$M2:$PATH